# Composer - Include PHP-Lib .so or .dll

Tags: php, composer-php, continuous-deployment, paas, ioncube

we are working with an ioncube encrypted webshop system. I'm evaluating how to setup continues deployment with this system.

Propably my assumtions are basically wrong. If this is the case I would be very gratefull if you have tips or corrections for me.

I would like to use an paas-provider like Heroku for the deployment. Heroku offers the possibility to load PHP-Modules like GD with composer. So I thought there might be a way to use Composer for loading Ioncube. But I can't find any introduction for composer that mentions .so or .dll files, which normally would be included in the php.ini configuration file.

If it doesn't work with Heroku, do you know any good paas-provider/hoster matching those reqiurements:

- PHP 5.4 and greater
- GDLib, Imagick, mod_rewrite, curl
- editable PHP-configuration (safe_mode off, register_globals off, memory_limit, max_file_size, max transfer size (Post))
- Suitable for continuous delivery (e.g. usage of git)
- horizontal scaling available
- backup & load balancing available by default
- MySQL database
- Ideally the paas-provider/hoster should offer a managed mail server

Thanks right now for you help.

Comment: Composer is not for managing PHP extensions and as far as I'm aware can't manage them.  Also, mod_rewrite isn't a PHP extension, it's an Apache module.

Comment: @GordonM Heroku uses the composer files to determine which optional extensions to load. See https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/php-support#extensions

Answer (score 1):

[Ioncube is not available/loadable on Heroku.](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/php-support#extensions)

I suspect you must search for an alternative Hoster yourself. Such questions do not have a good stand on Stackoverflow as they are mostly subjective, attract advertisement and one can google oneself.